# Why inherited static variables are accessible to non static method of subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have  question in my mind, why any inherited static variable and methods are  accessible to non  static  method of subclass.Isn`t it  violation  of  keyword static?
code

```
package com.pack1;
public class MyClass {
    static protected int testpro =100;

    protected static void  chkstat()
    { 
        System.out.println("check stat");
    }
}


package com.pack2;
import com.pack1.MyClass;
public class Test extends MyClass {
    public void fromsup() {
        System.out.println("" + this.testpro + "");
        testpro = 200;
        chkstat();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test tt = new Test();
    tt.fromsup();   
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Isn`t it violation of keyword static?"* - Keywords can't be "violated".  The worst that it can be is something that contradicts your mental model of how `static` should behave.  But that simply means that your mental model is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Not just subclasses, they're accessible as though they were instance variables within the class itself as well. It's just a quirk of Java syntax, it's mentioned in the JLS, [§8.3.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) and [§15.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11) (specifically [§15.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1)). Basically, the expression prior to the `.` is evaluated (in your case, it's a very simple expression: `this`) and, if it refers to an instance, that result is discarded and only the type information is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private static method and variable if you want them to not be accesible by subclasses. Same principles of access rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the instances of the class share the same copy of the static variable (in your case fromsup) I don't see violations of any sort.

Consider this

```
Test ob=new Test();
ob.fromsup=12;
Test oc=new Test();
System.out.println(oc.fromsup);
```

The output is still 12..